# json string do not fit in my made class using Xamarin

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

i´m in the middle of a project and i just got stuck. My problem is parsing the Json string to my class. This is my Json:

```
{
    "ReturnCode": 0,
    "CampaignId": 155087586,
    "TotalSMSSent": 1,
    "TotalSMSwithError": 0,
    "MSISDNwithErrorList": {

    }
}
```

and this is my class

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int ReturnCode { get; set; }

    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

    public int TotalSMSSent { get; set; }

    public int TotalSMSwithError { get; set; }

    public List<MSISDNwithErrorList> MSISDNwithErrorList { get; set; }
}

public class MSISDNwithErrorList
{
}
```

this is my code to get the json string

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var response = client.GetAsync("http://evolus.ddns.net/Q4Evolution/php/phpCategoria/BOPesquisaEmp.php").Result;
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(output);
}
```

And the error is this...

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "{"ReturnCode":0,"CampaignId":155087586,"TotalSMSSent":1,"TotalSMSwithError":0,"MSISDNwithErrorList":{}}" to type 'AppTeste.RootObject'. Path '', line 1, position 115.

Comment: why are you serializing the json returned by your webservice?  And then immediately deserializing it?  That doesn't make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSISDNwithErrorList  member seems only object as per the json structure

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int ReturnCode { get; set; }

    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

    public int TotalSMSSent { get; set; }

    public int TotalSMSwithError { get; set; }

    //Change from List to Object
    public MSISDNwithErrorList MSISDNwithErrorList { get; set; }   
}
```

Rest of Code should be like ...

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var response =client.GetAsync("http://evolus.ddns.net/Q4Evolution/php/phpCategoria/BOPesquisa
    Emp.php").Result;

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

   //Here Result already gives you a valid json, you do not need to serialize again
   string output =response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
   //obj is your desired c# object
   var obj =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(output);
}
```

You can check your working code on https://dotnetfiddle.net/CeXDNA

Comment: I have tried the 2 ways, i wiil change to object but the error is still the same

Comment: @Tiagodias I Edit my answer!!

Comment: @Tiagodias Your Welcome, If this solved yor issue, Please accept this as answer !!